# Rails -- uninitialized constant error for newly installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, koala, uninitialized-constant, fb-graph

I'm having trouble using newly installed gems - I think there must be something I'm missing, because I ran across the same error with both fb_graph and koala.  I added the gem to my gemfile and then `bundle install`ed it.  I thought that was all you had to do, so I then tried using commands demonstrated in their respective wikis on github to see if they would work for me.

In the case of Koala, I added the line `@graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new` to my Pages controller which displays `pages#home`.  I got the error `uninitialized constant PagesController::Koala`.

In the case of FB_Graph, I added the line `user = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN)` and got the error `uninitialized constant PagesController::FBGraph`.

Clearly I'm not doing something right - maybe there's something about configuring gems I installed that I'm missing - not really sure.  I've never really messed around with the FB API before, so it's possible the error is specifically related to FB gems.  Please advise.

Comment: Have you required the gem by adding `require 'koala'` before you try to access its class? `https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki`

Comment: yes - it says `no such file to load -- koala` and in the case of fb_graph it says `no such file to load -- fb_graph`

Comment: try just `gem install gem_name` at the command line first. Then `bundle install` again.

Comment: e.g. `gem install koala`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
gem install koala

gem install fb_graph
```

first

and restart your rails server and it should now have it.

Comment: solved the issue - I think it was mostly that I forgot to restart the rails server so I was running a previous one before I had installed the gem.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to require the gem. Add these to the top of your controller.

`require "koala"`

`require "fbgraph"`